# how can i create a new file in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for name in names:
    with open(f"/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Output/ReadyToSend/new.txt") as file:
        final = letter
        final.replace("[name]", name)
        file.write(final)
```

trying to create a new file for each name in the list of names, but it doesn't work. getting the below error. thanks.

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Output/ReadyToSend/Aang\n.txt'

was expecting that a new file would be created for each name. am i doing it wrong or is there a different way of achieving what i'm expecting.

EDIT: thanks for the responses. originally i had an f string ending with "/ReadyToSend/{name}.txt", expecting a new file to be created using the name from the for loop.

still getting an error. i've added the full code.

```
with open("/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as invited_names_file:
    names = invited_names_file.readlines()

with open("/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt") as starting_letter_file:
    letter = starting_letter_file.read()

filename = "/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Output/ReadyToSend/new.txt"

for name in names:
    with open(file=filename.replace("new", name), mode="w") as file:
        final = letter
        final.replace("[name]", name)
        file.write(final)
```

FINAL: thanks for all the help! figured it out and got it working! but if anyone has suggestions on cleaning it all up, please let me know. final code is below. a new file was created for each name, and the contents of each file are directed to the person the file is named after, as was desired.

```
with open("/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as invited_names_file:
    names = invited_names_file.read().split('\n')

with open("/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt") as starting_letter_file:
    letter = starting_letter_file.read().strip('\n')

filename = "/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Output/ReadyToSend/new.txt"

for name in names:
    with open(file=filename.replace("new", name), mode="w") as file:
        final = letter
        final = final.replace("[name]", name)
        file.write(final)
        print(final)
```

not totally sure on what strip() did but it did work, so if someone could clear that up that would be appreciated!

Comment: you need a new name for each file

Comment: Also, `Aang\n.txt` looks like a wrong filename. Also, `final.replace()` doesn't do anything, because the return value is discarded.

Comment: You can't write to a file unless it's been opened in one of various writable modes. You're opening (implicitly) readonly

Comment: Your path starting with Users and including Desktop seems to imply that you're using Windows, and yet you're using a Unix filepath?

Comment: Please test my last update to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the name of the file before creating it:

```
filename = f"/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Output/ReadyToSend/new.txt"
for name in names:
    with open(filename.replace("new", name), "w") as file:
        file.write("test")
```

Comment: `filename.replace(...)` won't do anything, because 1) `filename` doesn't containt `[name]`, 2) replace doesn't modify in-place.

Comment: In python strings are immutable, so, `replace()` doesn't modify the variable *(`2) replace doesn't modify in-place.`)*.  It just returns a new string, which you then do nothing with.  Try `filename = filename.replace("new", name)`  Also, don't use `open()` and `close()`, just use `with`, as per the original question.

Comment: could you guys have another look, i've added the full code, still getting the same error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the file path is valid. (Including C:\ if you're on windows)
2. Specify the `mode` in which you want to open the file, you are opening it in read mode.
3. You're not creating a new file, you're opening the same one, you need to specify a different path.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of '\n' in your filenames

```py
with open("/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as invited_names_file:
  names = invited_names_file.read().split('\n')

with open("/Users/XYZ/Desktop/technology/z 100 days of code z/python/Day 24 Mail+Merge+Project+Start/Mail Merge Project Start/Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt") as starting_letter_file:
    letter = starting_letter_file.read().strip('\n')
```

Comment: thanks, i did what you did with the names and this helped create new files with each name. why would i do the same for the letter? is it not just one big string, and so the presence of "[name]" in the letter should be replaced by the name from the list of names? doing what you did for the letter is making a list of strings; the default letter file starts with a generic "Dear [name]" and i want each new file to have the "[name]" part replaced with an actual name.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Open_Files():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def read_lines(self, file_location):
        with open(file_location) as letter_format:
            self = letter_format.readlines()
            return self
        


letter = Open_Files()
letter_format= letter.read_lines("Mail Merge Project Start/Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt")
name = letter.read_lines("Mail Merge Project Start/Input/Names/invited_names.txt")
for item in letter_format:
    for i in name:
        each_letterline=item.replace("[name]",i.strip())
        with open(f"Mail Merge Project Start/Output/ReadyToSend/letter_for_{i.strip()}.txt",mode="a") as letter_to_send:
                
                letter_to_send.write(each_letterline)
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: ...And more specifically, what benefit does the `Open_Files` class provide?